# How to play youtube videos using YouTube API inside a viewpager?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have an activity supporting a viewpager. I need to play youtube videos inside each fragment of the viewpager using the youtube API. I've tried using YouTubeSupportFragment and implementing fragment inside the viewpager fragment but none work. How do I approach and resolve this problem? I can provide thee code in-person too.

Comment: are you trying to copy inshorts?

Answer (score -1):

Here describe all that you need to implement YouTube Video play. Download YouTubeAndroidPLayerAPI from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/).

After that register your app on [Google console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register#installed-applications).

You can check setup instruction [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup)  or [Download example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications)

Comment: I have done it all. The problem is implementation of api in viewpager fragments.

Comment: This does not address the question. The question is know the implementation of youtube api with in a fragment inside a swipe enable view pager.